# "retrieved hash chain is invalid"

Tags: go-ethereum, light-clients, android

I am currently having problems syncing with rinkeby - was working (very) fine before - anyone else experiencing this?

```
04-21 03:11:59.352 24740 24767 E GoLog   : INFO [04-21|01:11:59] Block synchronisation started 
04-21 03:12:00.256 24740 24767 E GoLog   : INFO [04-21|01:12:00] Imported new block headers               count=3 elapsed=417.961ms number=48445 hash=282d54…00bfd3 ignored=0
04-21 03:15:42.241 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:15:42] Rolled back headers                      count=14 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:15:42.241 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:15:42] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:15:43.051 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:15:43] Rolled back headers                      count=14 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:15:43.051 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:15:43] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:16:12.223 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:12] Rolled back headers                      count=16 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:16:12.223 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:16:12.999 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:12] Rolled back headers                      count=16 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:16:12.999 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:16:26.983 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:26] Rolled back headers                      count=17 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:16:26.983 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:26] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:16:43.251 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:43] Rolled back headers                      count=18 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:16:43.251 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:16:43] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:17:12.079 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:12] Rolled back headers                      count=20 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:17:12.079 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:17:13.316 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:13] Rolled back headers                      count=20 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:17:13.316 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:13] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:17:42.345 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:42] Rolled back headers                      count=22 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:17:42.346 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:42] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:17:43.430 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:43] Rolled back headers                      count=22 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:17:43.430 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:17:43] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:18:12.070 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:12] Rolled back headers                      count=24 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:18:12.070 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:18:13.570 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:13] Rolled back headers                      count=24 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:18:13.571 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:13] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:18:42.060 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:42] Rolled back headers                      count=26 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:18:42.060 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:42] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:18:43.652 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:43] Rolled back headers                      count=26 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:18:43.652 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:18:43] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:19:12.170 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:12] Rolled back headers                      count=28 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:19:12.171 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:19:13.722 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:13] Rolled back headers                      count=28 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:19:13.722 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:13] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:19:27.154 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:27] Rolled back headers                      count=29 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:19:27.154 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:27] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:19:43.887 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:43] Rolled back headers                      count=30 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:19:43.887 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:19:43] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=a24ac7c5484ef4ed err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:20:12.174 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:20:12] Rolled back headers                      count=32 header=48445->48445 fast=0->0 block=0->0
04-21 03:20:12.175 24740 24767 E GoLog   : WARN [04-21|01:20:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=483c1910a306d333 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"
04-21 03:20:14.044 24740 24767 E GoLog   : INFO [04-21|01:20:14] Imported new block headers               count=33 elapsed=51.046ms  number=48478 hash=d71653…20e950 ignored=0
```

Answer (score 5):

As per my experience, it happens if your local node clock is not syned with ntp. For instance below command will sync your node with ntp (tested on ubuntu);

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Now you can try again

Comment: Thanks for sharing this insight - but the workaround is not really applicable to me as I am on android - updating the clock would require root AFAIK